# Delphi existing application connect to cloud

Tags: mysql, database, delphi, cloud

I have my application in Delphi with MySQL as a database. This is a Desktop application with local Database connected using ADO components.

I have another web application done in PHP and MYSQL.
I want to merge both databases and connect the Delphi application to the cloud MySQL database.

Do I need to put all my logic in PHP scripts and access them from Delphi?
How Delphi to cloud connection can be established?

Comment: @fpiette is right, We generally do not use mysql as a local database but sqlite. use php/java/python/go manager the MySQL, and use http-get/post in delphi by REST and Json

Comment: Have you tried using the (php) mysql connection details in the ado components?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FireDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Overview_(FireDAC)) to connect to a database located in the cloud, as soon as your provider allows that connectivity.

But exposing you database to the internet is not the best secure architecture. As you suggest yourself with naming it, a much better architecture is [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). The idea is to write server side software - could be PHP - to accept REST requests from a client, execute it (access the database) and send a reply to the client.

Today's, the REST requests are frequently using [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to pass requests and receive replies. JSON is supported by Delphi. In short, this is an ASCII representation for object properties.

If accessing the database directly is what you really want, look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Vn891LCjlg) by Stephen Ball showing how to access an MS-SQL database on Azure cloud. This would be pretty well the same with mySQL.